# Why is it printing Enter month twice?

Tags: java

```
do {
    System.out.print("\t\tEnter month: ");
    String mnth = inp.next();
    startmnth = val(mnth);
    if (startmnth >= 0) {
        break;
    } else {
        System.out.println("\t\tValid inputs are only January and so on");
    }
} while (true);
```

I'm having a problem with the println Enter month:
It's printing out twice rather than once.

Comment: `next` isn't consuming the dangling new line character until the second time round through the loop - consider making using of `nextLine`

Comment: Is it possible to put the full code? I can try going through a debugger to check

Answer (score -1):

you need change `inp.next()` to `inp.nextLine()`

Comment: hmmm it's stil the same though nothing new